# FancyBox: one function only taken into account

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox({
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: 'float'
            }
        },
        beforeShow: function () {
            this.title = '<div>' + jQuery(this.element).next('div').html() + '</div>';
        }
    });

    jQuery("a.fancybox").fancybox({
        tpl: {
            next: '<a title="Avanti" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-next"><span></span></a>',
            prev: '<a title="Indietro" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-prev"><span></span></a>'
        }
    });
});
```

The first part (.fancybox) is "ignored", the second (a.fancybox) is taken into account. If I remove the second, the first is taken into account. -_-

You can see the code I'm talking about here: http://goo.gl/uuv5y
Unfortunately because it's a live site I only left the first part and removed the TPL one..

Comment: Why not just use one fancybox initialisation?

Comment: why you need to call two fancybox.. when one works...either call tpl in first...or beforeShow and helpers in second..use only one fancybox

Comment: Of course, the second overrides the first one because both bind the same selector. You can set all the options in a single script.

Comment: Not sure why two fancyboxs are being used here, since at most you'd need to call one of them per interaction. Have you tried simply placing the TPL one in above the other one?

Comment: Uhm because the second should be applied to a.fancybox only (not .fancybox).. I think :D

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno : `a.fancybox` and `.fancybox` are exactly the same